# Node showing teaser, but not content

Tags: views, users, organic-groups

My view is showing the list of teasers correctly, but when I want to read more and see the full body text I get the "Page not found" error. I've been searching through all my settings, permissions etc. and can't find the error. It might have something to do with the view, but I can't see any error there either. Any ideas?

Screenshot of the view settings:
[image]

I can easily find the node body in the MySQL table `field_data_body`.

Comment: Does the read more link contain the correct url? And what happens when you type the correct url in the browser bar?

Comment: Yes, the read more link contains the correct url.

Comment: Cross check with the read more URL and the node page URL, whether they are same or different. And also check your URL redirects settings.

Comment: They are the same but with different node id. `/node/%/`

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution in case it is not working. Include title, body (trimmed) and global text contain

```
<a href=[node:url]>Read More</a>
```

Make sure include node path and drag it above so that it appears in replacement pattern down below

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Add '**title field**' two times as shown in below image.

[image]

For last '**title field**', do the setting as shown in image below.

[image]

Make sure that "**Link this field to the original piece of content**" is checked. In Rewrite results your text could be anything like "Read more" or "Read full story"...

By this you will be directed to your original node page.

Comment: Getting a "Page not found" when I click "Read full story".

Comment: Have you checked by writing URL like localhost/example/node/nid for that particular content. Is that working fine ? Otherwise problem is in path. Check alias if you have used path auto.

Comment: No, it's not working when I enter direct url. How can I fix path?

Comment: Make sure that nid you entered was correct, because if its not working than question arises that 'where is the content ?' Every content has a system path like node/nid.

Comment: Well, parts of the content is shown in the teaser, so it's there somewhere. But not when I want to see the node with the full body etc.